# Is it possible to view the order in which tests were run in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, xunit

I am investigating a Heisenbug in a large suite of tests in a VS solution. I suspect it may depend on the order in which the tests are run. Obviously this is not an ideal situation.

But my question is, after a run, is there a way to see in what order the tests were executed?

Answer (score 1):

If the situation is reproductible then you can run your tests from command line with appropriate logging level set on runner to see the actual order of your test executions.

For example `dotnet test -v d YourProject.Tests.dll` will output status, testmethodname and timing (because of verbosity set to detailed via `-v d`) for each test on separate lines in the executed order.

Comment: Definitely better than nothing. Not a full win because sometimes these things show up once a week or so. But if they are quasi-reproducible, this will do it.

Comment: Additionally I found a file with .testlog extension under .vs folder which is written during test execution. It looks a structured binary file with human readable test method names included, but I haven't found any parsers in 5 minutes I spent with it.